# How do i copy my transpose data with the cell's fill color together?

Tags: excel, vba

```
     Sub Button1_Click()

     For i = 1 To 6
     Worksheets("SHIPMENT OI").Range("B2:B50").Select
     Selection.Copy
     Worksheets("SHIPMENT OI").Range("B51").Select

     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
     Worksheets("SHIPMENT OI").Range("B50").Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Next

     End Sub
```

Hi Everyone,

may i know how do i maintain the code above and copy my cells color together?

aiming to transpose my cells and place them below along with the cells color/format.

Need some advice

Thanks in advance!

[VBA Transpose Data done but cells copied without its cell color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9pM.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `Paste:=xlPasteAll`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype. Also: Don't use `Select`. Obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas! appreciate it! Hmm okay I shall take a look at the link you shared. I followed this code from YouTube, really know nuts about VBA but slowly learning on it. Once again thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a loop (from 1 to 6)? You are executing the same Copy&Paste 6 times! And you should use `Option Explicit`  and declare all your variables